# I accidentally deleted the /etc/rc3.d directory on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation can someone list the contents for me?

Tags: boot, init.d, etc

I accidentally deleted the /etc/rc3.d directory on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation can someone list the contents for me, with ls -all so I can see the symbolic links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try `extundelete` to recover it

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it turns out that the contents of /etc/rc2.d, /etc/rc3.d, /etc/rc4.d, and /etc/rc5.d are identical.

You can use one of the others to copy back over to it